Trying to read frames from a Raspberry Pi camera module with OpenCV, but frames appear black
I'm trying to capture an image from my Raspberry Pi camera module using OpenCV. The code runs without errors, but the frame I get is completely black.
When I use rpicam-still -o Desktop/image.jpg I am able to get a still picture from the camera. However, when I run this code that I found on the internet, I only get a completely black frame. I'm not sure where I got it from, but it's a generic code that just tries to use OpenCV.
The code:(update 2)
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(-1)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame.max(), frame.mean()) 
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    print(f"Max Pixel Value: {frame.max()}, Mean Pixel Value: {frame.mean()}")
    print(f"Frame Shape: {frame.shape}, Frame Data Type: {frame.dtype}")

    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv.imwrite('frame.png', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()   


Output I'm receiving:
/
Max Pixel Value: 0, Mean Pixel Value: 0.0
Frame Shape: (480, 640, 3), Frame Data Type: uint8
0.0.0
enter image description here--> Here’s the frame I’m getting.
/
Update:
Right now, this is what my code looks like after the modifications you suggested. However, the result remains the same, as I still get a black frame. At this point, I've modified pretty much everything that was suggested, but I didn't set an exposure time in this code because I tried it earlier, and it didn't seem to improve anything. If anyone thinks I should try setting the exposure time again, please let me know, and also if any more information is needed.
Update(2)
So, I made more additions to the code, and here is what it looks like after the latest update. At this point, I’m thinking it might be more of a system issue—it seems like it’s trying to open the camera but doesn’t recognize the image it’s receiving or something like that. As you mentioned, OpenCV doesn’t support the Raspberry Pi camera directly and should return an error when trying to access it. I also tried the Picamera code you suggested, but I’m still getting a similar error as with this code. So maybe the Raspberry Pi 3 is the main villain here, as its processing capacity for handling images isn’t that great. But that’s just a thought of mine. What do you guys think?
Also, I'm running this in Thonny IDE, and I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 (with Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit) with a RaspiCam module. I already checked the OpenCV installation, and everything seems to be fine, but I’ll include the versions of Python and OpenCV that I'm using:
$ pip show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.10.0.84
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: Apache 2.0

$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2

(This is my first time posting here, and English is not my native language, so let me know if you have any questions about my writing or the data I provided.)

You may need to set an exposure time and/or tell it explicitly to take an image before the camera's  image buffer has anything in it to read. Also try histogram equalisation on your image in case the scaling is wrong or exposure time far too short.

thanks, i'll try it and later on i give an update here.

So far, I haven't seen any change after adding this to my code. I could try modifying the exposure, but I'm not really sure what exposure value to use.

Try addinng this line after reading the frame print(frame.max(), frame.mean()) to see the brightest sample and mean brightness. Also, try adding cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame) to save a PNG, then look at the frame with an image viewer app and try stretching the contrast.

Please, [edit] and update your question and the provided [mcve] (for example, you removed that excess cv.waitKey() which made it wait forever for a keypress after each frame). Also give us some of the info that Mark is asking above. It would be also useful to investigate the state of the available VideoCapture properties to see what the state of things like exposure rate and various auto gain/exposure/white balance is.

I had to delete my answer. Here is link. https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/use-picamera2-take-photos-with-raspberry-pi

I've edited the code now—sorry for not doing it earlier. If you think I should add more data, please let me know.

You cannot use OpenCV format. If you use Raspverry Pi3 or later,  then Picamera 2  for Bookworm. To use OpenCV format . You use USB webcam. Btw, PiCamera 2, is already installed.

I'll admit I'm not big fan of the VideoIO module of OpenCV. Did you consider trying the picamera module instead?

So, I have to change the way I get the frame, but can I still use OpenCV to examine the image I get?

Yeah, I can't imagine the conversion being a big deal. Quick search yields this example:  https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html

use any other way to access the camera, any way that does NOT involve OpenCV. use existing programs rather than code. does any such way "work"?

I will try that. I'll give you guys an update later on about how it's going. Thanks for the help so far!

yeah, when i use raspstill it "works".

I'm surprised OpenCV doesn't just fail outright to access that camera. OpenCV has no backend for the picamera/2 stuff.

BTW, one more thing to add in an [edit] -- the output of those print statements.

the VideoCapture constructor not failing means one of two things. either something presents this camera as a V4L device, or OpenCV gained a libcamera backend. either way, something's fishy. we definitely need to know more about frame's content, such as the requested max and mean. .shape and .dtype would also be vital to have. also seconding use of any python package interfacing with libcamera/2 instead of using OpenCV for the retrieval.

Hey guys, good morning (I’m from Brazil, so I’m not sure if it’s morning where you are, but you get the idea!). I made some edits to the post, and I hope it helps you understand better what I’m getting from the code

an RPi3 should be plenty. unless the hardware is literally incompatible, I don't think the hardware is the issue. might be a system/config issue. you did say you could get a usable picture using rpicam-still.  if I got that right, the camera works in principle, and it works with your system, and the issue should just be APIs.

Sorry, I had to delete my answer.

OP was saying that,
I'm using the Raspberry Pi Camera Module, which connects directly to the port between the HDMI and the audio (P2) ports. It's a CSI
connector that uses a flat cable

To use Picamera 2 for Bookworm:
Snippet:
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time
picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()
picam2.configure(camera_config)
picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)
picam2.capture_file("test.jpg")

You can learn tutorial from the link: PiCamera 2

I removed the cap.waitKey() line, but I still get a black frame. I'll make more modifications and wait a bit to see if anything changes, but thanks!

Are you using bookworm?

I'm using both Bulleyes and Bookworm

i'm using just bookworm, do you think i should use Bulleyes too?

I have two Micro SD Card. One for Bulleyes and and one for Bookworm. This is how I do.

Are you using USB webcam? It is USB2.0 or USB3.0?

I'm using the Raspberry Pi Camera Module, which connects directly to the port between the HDMI and the audio (P2) ports. It's a CSI connector that uses a flat cable.

OIC. You have to use PICAMERA 2 module format not an OpenCV

https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/use-picamera2-take-photos-with-raspberry-pi
